# Select is showing the selected option partially

Tags: css, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this problem. Whenever I use a select box, it only shows the selected option partially, like this:

[image]

This is the corresponding portion of the code:

```
<div class="col col-33">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">CALIBRE CABLE (AWG)</div>
    <div class="col"><label class="item item-input item-select">
<div class="input-label"></div>
    <select id="calibreMedRspta">
        <option disabled selected>Seleccione el calibre:</option>
        <option>350</option>
        <option>250</option>
        <option>4/0</option>
        <option>3/0</option>
        <option>2/0</option>
        <option>1/0</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>6</option>
        <option>8</option>
        <option>10</option>
        <option>12</option>
    </select></label></div>
</div>
```

I'm using Phonegap, and ionic CSS (not the entire framework).

[jsfiddle with ionic 1.2.4 CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/4v47u1vy/)

[ionic documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select)

Comment: This look like a css problem. Can you add the CSS style to the question please?

Comment: Well, it's the ionic.css from the ionic framework. It's over nine thousand lines ;) (ooops! I forgot the ionic tag!)

Comment: created this jsfiddle with ionic 1.2.4 CSS and your html https://jsfiddle.net/4v47u1vy/ documentation wise : http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#select

Comment: some tweaks defining the grid might be all it needs https://jsfiddle.net/4v47u1vy/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I fixed it by modifying the "width" of the select in the css file.

Comment: @Rodriguez for responsiveness, you could use the "display: table" style property for option element.

Answer (score 0):

Add to CSS file:

```
option { display: table; }
```

or

Add to style attribute of option:

```
<option style="display: table;" value="AsLongAsItCanBe">Value1</option>
```